# bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash

I'm trying to customize the .bashrc but I'm getting the following error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/')'
```

This is what I have inside .bashrc file:

```
export PS1="[\A \d] \[\033[32m\]\h@\u\[\033[m\] \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[m\]> \[\033[36m\]\$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/')\[\033[m\]\n\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your current active branch, use:

```
git branch --show-current
```

Your shell error is: the `$` of your `$(git ...)` is escaped.